# running composer install in Dockerfile

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am trying to dockerize a PHP laravel app. I am using a PHP and a composer image to achieve this. However, when I run *composer install*, I get all my packages installed but then run into this error:

`/app/vendor does not exist and could not be created.`

I want composer to create the /vendor directory! Could this be a permission issue?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.3-cli

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

COPY --from=composer:2.4.4 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY . . 

# Add a new user "john" with user id 8877
RUN useradd -u 8877 john

# Change to non-root privilege
USER john

RUN composer install
```

I created a user with an arbitrary ID since it's a bad practice to run *composer install* as root security-wise.

Comment: It's bad practice to run composer install as root on your host machine. There's less of a security concern if it happens within a container since that is sandboxed

Comment: Fix your build first before being concerned about users within the docker container that specifically. As there is already a COPY operation, why not have what the output of `composer install`  is beforehand in the docker build context? (just my two cents, don't fix what is broken aftewards, have it fixed first)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by making some changes to my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.3-cli

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

COPY --from=composer:2.4.4 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

# Add a new user "john" with user id 8877
RUN useradd -u 8877 john

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY . . 

RUN chmod -R 775 /app
RUN chown -R john:john /app

# Change to non-root privilege
USER john

RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-plugins
```